# Programmatically backing up KACE dump files as of version 6?

Tags: powershell, kace

We use KACE system management appliances for some of our user systems.  As of KACE 5.x, you were able to download the backup files directly off of the appliance.  We utilized this method to backup our databases to tape on a script, below:

```
$TodaysDate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
$KaceRootDownloadUrl = "http://kace-url/common/download_file.php?FILENAME=/kbackup/"
$KaceDBFileName=$TodaysDate+"_k1_dbdata.gz"
$KaceKBoxFileName=$TodaysDate+"_kbox_file.tgz"

$KaceBackupFolder="D:\\backupfolder\\KACE\\"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile($KaceRootDownloadUrl+$KaceDBFileName, $KaceBackupFolder+$KaceDBFileName)
$WebClient.DownloadFile($KaceRootDownloadUrl+$KaceKBoxFileName, $KaceBackupFolder+$KaceKBoxFileName)
```

Unfortunately with the KACE 6.0 upgrade, this url now redirects to a login page.  I attempted to send credentials on the WebClient DownloadFile call, however it still redirected me to the login page.

Has anyone else dealt with this issue?  Is there a secret route that uses http auth instead of looking for a login cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the K1000 v6 software, the system automatically enables "require authentication to download backup images" -- one needs to disable that feature or switch to ftp if they want to download system backups going forward.